# Batch command to get the file path only, from a string

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've searched and found several examples on this, but I don't seem to get anything to work... I'm writing a simple Windows batch script to unzip files. In my batch script I have a variable, zipfile, that is dynamically assigned as the most recent Zip file in folder and subfolders:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir d:\temp\*.zip /s /b /od') do set zipfile=%%a
```

To simplify, considering the value:

```
set zipfile=d:\temp\mysubfolder\myfile.zip
```

How can I get the full path, "d:\temp\mysubfolder\" ? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("%zipfile%") do (set fullpath=%%~dpa)
Echo %fullpath%
```

Done! Make sure `%zipfile%` does not have surrounding quotes.

Mona

Comment: Thank you! Got my %fullpath% variable as I needed to proceed.

Comment: @mahiro shorter with the same result: `for %%a in ("%zipfile%") do set "fullpath=%%~dpa"`

Comment: @Endoro But that doesn't include for spaces

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't handle spaces?

Comment: Wait whoops, I thought it was `/f`.

Answer (score 2):

See the `call /?` for how to use labels inside a batch file.
It also explains how to extract the drive, path, and filename from a parameter.

```
set zipfile=d:\temp\mysubfolder\myfile.zip
call :SETZIPPATH %zipfile%
goto:eof 

:SETZIPPATH
set zippath=%~dp1
```

You can also do the call from inside the for loop.

Comment: Thank you! Went with the line of code above for my batch script, but appreciate the tip! I didn't know about these labels for batch files before, so it's something I learned for a next time.

Comment: Great.  I'm glad you learned something and I hope it makes it easier for you to batch something in the future.

Comment: +1 but a `call` is slower than `for /f`  --> http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=10681

Comment: Is it though?  I was able to run a crude test including 20 for loops vs. 20 label calls with `echo %time%` before and after.  I understand that part of the measurement is the `set` command, but they are identical in both cases.  It measured ~740ms for the for loop and ~670ms for the call.  I am not convinced that a for loop is quicker than the local call.  Again, I understand my measurement method is quite crude.